# font-face working on android phones but not tablets

Tags: android, css, font-face, tablet

I've been browsing stackoverflow and google and couldn't find a solution so far (even though I tried all those suggested).

I'm trying to embed a font on my website, and it works fine everywhere, except the Samsung Galaxy tab (android 4.something).

I used MyFonts.com to download the font and they say it is supported.
Here's how my css:

```
/* @import must be at top of file, otherwise CSS will not work */
@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/268362");


@font-face {
    font-family: 'FranklinGothicBT-ExtraCondensed';
    src: url('../fonts/268362_0_0.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/268362_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/268362_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/268362_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

The strange thing is that it works on android phones, but not tablets. Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem yet?

Comment: Yes, but I really can't remember what was causing the problem..

Comment: If you are not going to be able to select an answer, you might just remove your question then.

Comment: I didn't select your answer (the only one) because it didn't solve my problem. An unanswered question can still be useful to people.

Comment: I was not saying that you would need to select my answer, but your previous comment implies you would not be able to select any answer... ever. "...I really can't remember what was causing the problem." Also you would not be able to elaborate on the problem if someone asked. Which would eventually lead people down the road of one of the following: unclear, incomplete or overly-broad because you could not specify what exactly the problem is, which would lead to the question being removed after moderation. So I was just trying to save other people some time and energy.

Comment: I see, sorry I did not re-read my last comment. I'm going to leave this up so if anyone gets here he'll see your answer below, maybe that'll solve their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try linking to the font file from your HTML. Here is an example: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started?hl=de